# Autofac: Registering a Singleton and InstancePerDependency Dependency Relationship

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, autofac

I'm using Autofac for dependency injection in my .NET application. I have a scenario where I want to register a service as a singleton and its dependency as InstancePerDependency. Here's a simplified example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
builder.Register(c => new ClassA()).As<IClassA>().InstancePerDependency();

builder.Register(c => new ClassB(c.Resolve<IClassA>()))
       .As<IClassB>()
       .SingleInstance();
```

Will registering ClassB as a singleton affect IClassA's InstancePerDependency lifetime scope in this setup? If so, how can I achieve a singleton IClassA while ensuring that IClassA follows an InstancePerDependency lifetime scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Autofac, when you register a service as a singleton and its dependency as InstancePerDependency, the singleton service (ClassB in your case) will hold onto a single instance of its dependency (ClassA in your case) throughout its lifetime. This means that every time `ClassB` is resolved, it will use the same instance of `ClassA`.

If you want `ClassA` to follow an InstancePerDependency lifetime scope while ensuring that `ClassB` remains a singleton, you can achieve this by registering `ClassA` as a factory delegate rather than a concrete instance. Here's how you can modify your registration:

```
builder.Register(c => new ClassA()).As<IClassA>().InstancePerDependency();

builder.Register(c =>
{
    var classAFactory = c.Resolve<Func<IClassA>>();
    return new ClassB(classAFactory());
})
.As<IClassB>()
.SingleInstance();
```